# How to create a pop up window without any trim?

Tags: windows, eclipse, swt, jface

I am trying to create a pop-up window which has absolutely no trim.

I have tried the following but get a window with a very thin black border. My goal is to have no visible border at all.

```
public class PopupWithArrow extends PopupDialog
{

    public PopupWithArrow(Shell shell)
    {
        super(shell, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.NO_FOCUS, 
                false, false, false, false, false, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try `SWT.TOOL` rather than `SWT.NO_TRIM`

Comment: @greg-449 I tried that already. `TOOL` just adds a drop shadow - the border remains

Answer (score 0):

I used Windows calls to restyle the window and got the result I was looking for.

```
public class PopupWithArrow extends PopupDialog
{

    public PopupWithArrow(Shell shell)
    {
        super(shell, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.NO_FOCUS, 
                false, false, false, false, false, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        super.create();
        restyle();
    }

    public void restyle()
    {
        OS.SetWindowLongPtr(getShell().handle, OS.GWL_STYLE, OS.WS_POPUP);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only going to work on Windows. `OS` is completely different on each platform.